# Filter array with values from another array Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

Essentially, I am trying to filter out specific indices that are not in criteria array. Data that I am getting from JSOn file looks like this:

```
let data = [
        {
            "category": ["business"],
            "title": "some title"
        },
        {
            "category": ["travel", "business"],
            "title": "some title"
        },
        {
            "category": ["sport"],
            "title": "some title"
        },
        {
            "category": ["business", "sport"],
            "title": "some title"
        }
    ]
```

The array that should filter category of each object from the data above:

```
var criteria = ["business", "travel"]
```

I've tried numerous options, the ones that I've listed below are only the ones that either return something or not bring any errors, however, both methods do not bring desired outcome.

```
const filtered = data.filter((item) => 
   // this returns only first "business" category while ignoring the rest
   criteria.find(element => item.category == element)
) 

const filtered = data.filter((item) => 
   // this simply returns all data entries, even the ones that are not in criteria array.
   criteria.filter(element => item.category == element)
)
```

```
const filtered = spanishData.filter(function (item) {
    // returns all data entries as well
        return criteria.indexOf(item.category) === -1
    })
```

How can I filter the data > category array according to the criteria array?

Thank you

Comment: [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) always returns an Array and an Array is always [truthy](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `data.filter((item) => criteria.filter(`…`))` is effectively exactly the same as `data.filter(() => true)` which is the same as `data.slice()`. `item.category == element` doesn’t make sense: `item.category` is an Array. You can’t reliably compare it using `==`; comparing a String and an Array with `==` coerces both operands to strings and `"travel,business"` is not `"business,travel"`.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+filter+objects+where+array+property+contains+at+least+one+item+from+another+array) of [Filter array of objects where one object's array has at least one match with another array](/q/65550533/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
let data=[{category:["business"],title:"some title"},{category:["travel","business"],title:"some title"},{category:["sport"],title:"some title"},{category:["business","sport"],title:"some title"}],
criteria=["business","travel"];
let res = data.filter(x => x.category.some(c => criteria.includes(c)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: pretty sure this question has multiple duplicates, should have closed